# PHP: Hashing code not working any longer?

Tags: php, hash

I used this hash function for a while (got it from the internet). The thing is it used to work immediately but now it is complaining about a paramter. The following is the code:

```
function generateHash($plainText, $salt = null)
{

    if ($salt === null)
    {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    else
    {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    return $salt . sha1($salt . $plainText);
}
```

So I would use this code in the method call:

```
validateUserInput($userid, $pass);
```

and validateUserInput is:

```
function validateUserInput($username, $password)
{
    //$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    //$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    if(!$username || !$password)
    {
        //$errors['credentials'] = 'Missing Credentials!';
        //$_SESSION['errors_array'] = $errors;
        //echo $errors['credentials'];
        header("LOCATION:XXXXXXX.php");
    }

    $local_salt = generateHash($password);
    //echo $local_salt;
    $groupid;

    if($username != null && $password !=null)
    {   
        connectToServer();
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE hashkey = '{$local_salt}'");

        while($row_access = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $groupid = $row_access['groupid'];
        }
        if(!isset($result))
        {
            $errors['not_found_user'] = 'No Users Found with Provided Credentials!';
            //$_SESSION['errors_array'] = $errors;
            $userfound = 0;
            $_SESSION['user_available'] = $userfound;
        }elseif(isset($result)){
            $_SESSION['user_logged'] = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'salt' => $local_salt, 'groupid' => $groupid);
            $userfound = 1;
            //echo "stored";
            $_SESSION['user_available'] = $userfound;
        }       
    }
}
```

finally the error is:

```
Warning: substr() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in /home/XXXX.php on line 64
```

This is pointing to the function `generateHash()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error itself tells you everything. The constant `SALT_LENGTH` is not a `long`. I suspect it's not defined at all, so PHP converts the bare string to a string (`"SALT_LENGTH"`) and passes *that* to `substr()`, which complains.

That being said... This code is dangerously wrong:

1. `if(!isset($result))`: Really? This condition will *always* be false because `$result` will *always* be set (unless you run into a problem with `mysql_query()`, but that doesn't tell you anything about the valididty of the login). And since `mysql_query()` never returns `null`, **no logins will ever be rejected.**
2. This query:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE hashkey = '{$local_salt}'
   ```

   Is invalid. `$local_salt = generateHash($password);`. From the `generateHash` function, if a salt is not given, one will be randomly created for you. Thus, every call to `generateHash` will generate a new hash, which means it can't be compared to anything in the database.

On the basis of the two (very) egregious mistakes above, I would throw away this piece of code for good.

---

The correct way to check for a valid hash when a salt is used is something like:

```
$_SESSION['user_logged'] = null;

// fetch hashed pw from db, where username is the submitted username
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT hash FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'");

if ($result->num_rows != 0) 
{
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();    
     $hash = $row['hash'];

     $salt = substr($hash, 0, SALT_LENGTH); // extract salt 

     if (generateHash($password, $salt) == $hash) 
     {
         // login successful. 
         $_SESSION['user_logged'] = $username; // don't store passwords here
     }
}

// if $_SESSION['user_logged'] is not set, the login failed
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_logged'])) 
{
    // you *don't* want to tell people which one (login or pw) is invalid
    echo 'Invalid login or password';
}
```

Note: It's very important that the `SALT_LENGTH` is at most 32, or this won't work because of the way `generateHash()` is implemented.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. Thanks and will work on it. Nonetheless, your comment is not related to my question which is why would a piece of code that always worked stopped working!

Comment: @sys_debug Read the first paragraph. I am guessing it was working before because you had `SALT_LENGTH` defined in another file, which is now missing for whatever reason. Regardless, I am pointing out that even if it was "working" before, it wasn't doing the right thing.

Comment: aha thanks and really appreciate the help. Changing it now. Making sure the pitfalls u outlined above are avoided :)

Comment: ok before thinking about your implementation i did the following: (please inform me if it may work or not)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3976/discussion-between-nulluserexception---and-sys-debug)

Comment: aye this was solved...Thanks again mate for the great interest & help

Answer (score 2):

Clearly `SALT_LENGTH` is not an integer. Find where it's defined and correct this.

Comment: yes I know but it used to work all the time! I tried defining it by taking the strlen(salt) but didn't work because the salt is null when it enters the function and is generated in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a new hashing function each time you write an application , you should utilize the one provided to you by php: [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) ( i would recommend to go with any blowfish or sha256+ hash ).

And when selecting information from database, you should select it by username and then, with php, check if hash fits the password.

Comment: I already started doing this now...half way through it...and as u said, I am now checking username, then verifying the password hashed

Comment: @sys_debug , oh , and look into [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and prepared statements. Firstly because `mysql_*` function are ancient and soon gonna be deprecated, and secondly - if used correctly , prepared statements make it almost impossible to have an SQL injection in your code. Lets put it this way: you need a special kind of talent to make create an sql vulnerability, when using prepared statements.